# The parameterized query '(@username nvarchar(4000))DELETE FROM Staff WHERE Username=@user' expects the parameter '@username', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm having problems with my code:

```
public partial class DeleteStaff : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string username = null;
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    string connectionString = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if loading the page for the first time
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Check that there is an id passed in with the QueryString
            if (Request.Params["username"] != null)
            {
                // retrieve the id
                username = Convert.ToString(Request.Params["username"]);
            }

            // retrieve connectionString from Web.Config file
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMSCS"].ConnectionString;

            // create connection with database specified in the connectionString
            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            // prepare sql statement
            string sql = "DELETE FROM Staff WHERE Username=@username";

            try
            {    
                // create SqlCommand object with sql statement and connection
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

                // Open database connection
                conn.Open();

                // Execute SqlCommand
                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rows > 0)
                {
                    lblOutput.Text = "Record deleted successfully.";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblOutput.Text = "Record cannot be deleted.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = "Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once I press delete but for an particular item I get this error:

> The parameterized query '(@username nvarchar(4000))DELETE FROM Staff WHERE Username=@user' expects the parameter '@username', which was not supplied.

Comment: Are you sure that this code produces that error? The query text contains a parameter placeholder named `@username` however the error shows a different query with a placeholder `@user`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the AddWithValue method, use the the Add method and define the parameter type.  It appears that AddWithValue is guessing at the type (nvarchar(4000)).  The AddWithValue only accepts an object, so the parameter data type isn't being mapped correctly.

Example [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;
```

Comment: what is sqldbtype.int?

Comment: It is the type of value that you are passing to the database.  There  should be types for most of the data types in SQL Server.  I would recommend you look for a string or nvarchar type.

Comment: So if i want to pass in string, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

I think error happens when username == null. In this case parameter will not be added (DBNULL.Value and null differs).
It's better to check input parameter at first

```
if (Request.Params["username"] == null) throw ...
```

Comment: Good callout.  I get lazy with the DBnull.Value since the ORM that I use automatically converts the values.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: You always should check you request parameters in all procedures. In this case username cannot be null and you should throw exception if this happens

Comment: So you mean i have to put =""; instead of null?

Comment: No, you should show error message, because you cannot delete staff without name.

Comment: But i have name inside my database

Comment: Request.Params["username"] == null means that Staff has no name, I think it's impossible in your program. That's why you should show error. Also you should validate username on client side

Answer (score 0):

The username is the string that you should be passing into the database.